# error: file write error: Bad file descriptor fatal: unable to write sha1 file when using git add

Tags: gitlab

Suddenly I get this error when trying to add files. I'm running git on the headnote cluster on Linux and have enough space for my files. All my huge files are defined in `.gitignore`  file.

Error:

```
error: file write error: Bad file descriptor
fatal: unable to write sha1 file
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. In my case, the problem was the limited memory space, where my repository was. I moved the repository to another hard drive with more memory and it worked perfectly.